# How to combine raw with string interpolation in Scala?

Tags: scala

Just started Scala and have a question.

```
val num = 10
val str = "Learning\t${num}Scala"
```

Now I am trying to print `str` without escaping `\t` but with `num` interpolation.  Is this possible?  Tried couple of variations below but they didn't work

```
scala>s"${str}"
scala>s"""${str}"""
scala>raw"""${str}"""
```

The question is how do I print `Learning\t10Scala`

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - why not `s"Learning\t${num}Scala"`? You can't "delay" the interpolation, it can only be done upon String creation.

Comment: @TzachZohar Your example will replace `\t` with a Tab

Comment: `"""Learning\t""" + s"${num}Scala"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can be done, with same amount of code.

Write a function called times and make it insert some string in the middle of some other string

```
scala> def times(n: Int)(str: String): String = List.fill(n)(str).mkString("")
times: (n: Int)String

scala> s"""hello${times(3)("\t")}world"""
res0: String = hello            world
```